# I have Windows in English, can I have only the French Keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, user-interface

I want Windows to be in English (US). I would like to use all the applications in English US (apps like Windows Mail/Calendar by eg).

However I am in France and I use the French FR keyboard.

But I don't need the EN (US) Keyboard at all in the list. I have no such a keyboard in France, and I don't want to switch between keyboards I don't use.

So, Windows in **EN**, Application in **EN**, but the ***only*** keyboard I need is **FR**.

[image]

However, it seems Microsoft didn't think to such a case. In order to have, say, Windows Mail application interface in English, I need to add the English... KEYBOARD (?!!).

Is there a workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found myself a workaround:

I removed all languages but the English US from the settings, and for this language I added the French keyboard, and removed the existing English keyboard. So, English primary (and the only) language and French primary (and the only) keyboard.

[image]